# OpenCV threshold function

Tags: python, threshold

I'm looking for an OpenCV function in python, that is similar to THRESH_TOZERO_INV, but instead of 0 it returns maxvalue.
So instead of:

```
dst(x,y) =
{
 0         if src(x,y) > thresh
 src(x,y)  otherwise
}
```

I'm looking for:

```
dst(x,y) =
{
 maxvalue  if src(x,y) > thresh
 src(x,y)  otherwise
}
```

Is there an option like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `THRESH_BINARY` first, with a maxval of `1` then you will get a binary matrix with `0`s and `1`s. Call this matrix `M`. It has a `1` where `src(x,y) > thresh` and a `0` everywhere else.

Now compute

```
maxvalue * M + src * (1-M)
```

where `*` is the element-wise matrix-product and `1-M` means a matrix with all `1`s minus M, i.e. invert the binary matrix `M`.